# Proving $\left| z'\right| + \left| z\right| = \left| \frac{z+z'}{2}- \alpha \right| + \left| \frac{z+z'}{2}+ \alpha \right|$ given $zz'= \alpha^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do you prove
$$
\left| z'\right| + \left| z\right| = \left| \frac{z+z'}{2}- \alpha \right| + \left| \frac{z+z'}{2}+ \alpha \right|
$$
given
$$
zz'= \alpha^2
$$
for each complex number $z$ , $\alpha $, and $z’$?

Comment: Is $z'$ the conjugate here?

Comment: Nope sir, z, alpha and z' are elements of the set C.

Answer (score 5):

We can write $z=u^2$, $z'=v^2$, $\alpha=uv$.
Then the equation is equivalent to
$$2|u|^2+2|v|^2=|u+v|^2+|u-v|^2.$$
This is the [*parallelogram identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).